# Ayuda como pasar todo a Texto en C

Tags: c

El codigo crea nodos y los guarda en un archivo `.bin` y al final los guarda y cuando lo vuelvo abrir recupera lo que ya tiene el archivo binario. Todo esto lo hace con  el `"int"` o un numero.

**Lo que yo quiero es que en vez de hacerlo con numero, quiero que todo sea con texto** y es lo que no puedo hacer. OK si alguien me puede ayudar con la misma variable de `valor` quiero que en ves de `int` sea `char`, no modificar nada solo escribir texto en ves de numeros. Ayuda por favor. Lo siento si no me expreso bien pero si alguien me ayuda se lo agradecería mucho

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>

typedef struct NODE{ // En C hay que hacer typedef...
    int longitud;
    char *caracteres;
    node *ptrSiguiente; //me tira error "[Error] 'node' does not name a type"
} node;

node *ptrInicio = NULL;
node *ptrActual = NULL;
node *ptrNuevo = NULL;
node *ptrTemp = NULL;

void CrearNodo(char,int); // me dice "[Note] declared here"
void ImprimirNodos();
void GuardarLista();
void LeeNodoDesdeArchivo();
void Buscar(int bval);

int main(){

    LeeNodoDesdeArchivo();

    //Menu
    int opt = 1,bval=0;

    while(opt != 4){
        system("cls");
        printf("Menu de aplicacion\n\n");
        printf("1. Agregar Nodo\n");
        printf("2. Imprimir Lista\n");
        printf("3. Buscar\n");
        printf("4. Salir\n\n");
        printf("Seleccione una opcion: "); scanf("%d",&opt);

        if(opt == 1){
            char texto[10];
            system("cls");
            printf("Agregar Nuevo Nodo\n\n");
            printf("Ingrese Valor del Nodo: "); scanf("%s",&texto);
            CrearNodo(texto); //aqui me dice "[Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]" y tambien "[Error] too few arguments to function 'void CrearNodo(char, int)'"
            printf("\n\nNodo Creado!"); 
            system("pause");
        }

        if(opt == 2){
            system("cls");
            printf("Lista Actual:\n\n");
            ImprimirNodos();
            system("pause");
        }

        if(opt == 3){
            system("cls");
            printf("Buscar en la lista\n\n");
            printf("Ingrese valor de busqueda: "); scanf("%d",&bval);
            Buscar(bval);
            system("pause");
        }

    }

    GuardarLista(); 
}

void ImprimirNodos(){
    //Volvemos al inicio de la lista
    ptrTemp = ptrInicio;

    //Recorremos la lista   
    while(ptrTemp != NULL){
        printf("%d \n",ptrTemp->texto); // tambien aqui "[Error] 'node' has no member named 'texto'" lo que no se si la de lee nodo era aqui o lee nodo la cambiaba por cargar lista
        ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrSiguiente;
    }   

}

void Buscar(int bval){
    ptrTemp = ptrInicio;
    bool encontrado = false;
    int i=0;

    while(ptrTemp != NULL){
        if(ptrTemp->valor == bval){
            printf("Valor Encontrado!");
            printf("Valor en la Posicion: %d\n\n",i);

            encontrado = true;
        }

        i++;
        ptrTemp = ptrTemp->ptrSiguiente;

    }
    if(!encontrado){
        printf("El valor no existe en la lista.\n\n");
    }
}

void LeeNodoDesdeArchivo(FILE *archivo, node *nodo)
{
    fread(&nodo->longitud, sizeof(int),1,file);
    nodo->caracteres = (char*) malloc(nodo->longitud + 1);
    fread(&nodo->caracteres, sizeof(char),nodo->longitud,file);
    nodo->caracteres[nodo->longitud] = 0;
}


void GuardarLista(){
    ptrActual = ptrInicio;
    FILE *file = fopen("lista.bin","wb");

    while(ptrActual != NULL){
        // Guardamos la cantidad de caracteres que ocupa este nodo
        // pues lo necesitaremos para recuperar (leer) desde archivo.
        fwrite(ptrActual->longitud,sizeof(int),1,file);
        // Guardamos los caracteres, la longitud no incluye el
        // caracter final de cadena.
        fwrite(ptrActual->caracteres,sizeof(char),longitud,file);
        ptrActual = ptrActual->ptrSiguiente;
    }

    fclose(file);
}

void CrearNodo(char *texto, int longitud){

    // No es necesario duplicar la logica de creacion del nodo
    // hazlo tan solo una vez.
    ptrNuevo = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptrActual->ptrSiguiente = NULL;

    // Solicitamos tantos caracteres como larga sea la cadena
    // anyadiendo uno mas para el carácter nulo
    ptrNuevo->caracteres = (char*) malloc(longitud + 1);
    memcpy(ptrNuevo->caracteres, texto, longitud);
    ptrNuevo->caracteres[longitud] = 0;

    if(ptrInicio == NULL){
        //Primer Nodo
        ptrInicio = ptrNuevo;
        ptrActual = ptrInicio;
    }else{
        ptrActual->ptrSiguiente = ptrNuevo;
        ptrActual = ptrNuevo;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A diferencia de un número entero, una cadena de caracteres (*string*) no tiene un tamaño fijo. Dicho de otra manera tanto el número `1` como el número `7654321` ocupan 32bits<sup>1</sup>, pero las cadenas `"Ataulfo Perez de la Chinchilla"` y `"Paco Pocero"` ocupan 30 y 11 bits respectivamente<sup>2</sup>.

Así pues, para almacenar datos de texto no puedes usar el nodo tal y como lo tienes y como tampoco puedes usar la misma lógica de escritura en archivo; en este caso deberás separar el dato de texto en dos componentes:

- Longitud.
- Caracteres.

Para ello, tu nodo debería ser así:

```
typedef struct NODE{ // En C hay que hacer typedef...
    int longitud;
    char *caracteres;
    node *ptrSiguiente;
} node;
```

Esto significa que tus nodos ya no ocuparán en memoria un tamaño homogéneo, si no que dependiendo de lo larga que sea la cadena que almacenan ocuparán más o menos; esto afecta a la lógica de lectura, guardado y creación.

La lógica para crearlo deberá cambiar de la siguiente manera:

```
void CrearNodo(char *texto, int longitud){

    // No es necesario duplicar la logica de creacion del nodo
    // hazlo tan solo una vez.
    ptrNuevo = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptrActual->ptrSiguiente = NULL;

    // Solicitamos tantos caracteres como larga sea la cadena
    // anyadiendo uno mas para el carácter nulo
    ptrNuevo->caracteres = (char*) malloc(longitud + 1);
    memcpy(ptrNuevo->caracteres, texto, longitud);
    ptrNuevo->caracteres[longitud] = 0;

    if(ptrInicio == NULL){
        //Primer Nodo
        ptrInicio = ptrNuevo;
        ptrActual = ptrInicio;
    }else{
        ptrActual->ptrSiguiente = ptrNuevo;
        ptrActual = ptrNuevo;
    }   
}
```

La lógica de guardado debe tener en cuenta el tamaño variable de los nodos, en lugar de guardar los nodos como bloques monolíticos se deben guardar componente a componente:

```
void GuardarLista(){
    ptrActual = ptrInicio;
    FILE *file = fopen("lista.bin","wb");

    while(ptrActual != NULL){
        // Guardamos la cantidad de caracteres que ocupa este nodo
        // pues lo necesitaremos para recuperar (leer) desde archivo.
        fwrite(ptrActual->longitud,sizeof(int),1,file);
        // Guardamos los caracteres, la longitud no incluye el
        // caracter final de cadena.
        fwrite(ptrActual->caracteres,sizeof(char),longitud,file);
        ptrActual = ptrActual->ptrSiguiente;
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Fíjate que **sólo se guarda `longitud` y `caracteres`**, no tiene sentido guardar el puntero al siguiente nodo ya que su valor va a cambiar por cada ejecución del programa. En cuanto a la lectura desde archivo, se hará de la misma manera: leyendo primero la longitud y luego los caracteres, veámoslo:

```
void LeeNodoDesdeArchivo(FILE *archivo, node *nodo)
{
    fread(&nodo->longitud, sizeof(int),1,file);
    nodo->caracteres = (char*) malloc(nodo->longitud + 1);
    fread(&nodo->caracteres, sizeof(char),nodo->longitud,file);
    nodo->caracteres[nodo->longitud] = 0;
}
```

#### A tener en cuenta.

Hay cosas en tu código que pese a no ser incorrectas es necesario puntualizar.

- Evita el uso de variables globales: las variables globales hacen que sea más difícil seguir la lógica del código, transforma `ptrInicio`, `ptrActual`, `ptrNuevo` y `ptrTemp` en variables locales.
- Deberías comprobar el retorno de `fopen` en lugar de usar su retorno directamente: en caso de que la apertura de archivo falle `fopen` devolverá `NULL` y usar un puntero a `FILE` nulo provoca errores en tiempo de ejecución.
- En lugar de una cadena de `if`, cambia la comprobación de acción a realizar por un `switch`.

---

<sup>1</sup>En plataformas de 32bits, podrían ocupar 64 en plataformas de 64bits o 16 en plataformas de 16bits.

<sup>2</sup>Pudiendo variar también según la plataforma.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda te lo agradezco mucho, ya hice los cambios que me mandaste y gracias por la explicacion me hace entender cuales eran mis errores. Ahora tengo un problema donde me tira errore y no se porque. Disculpa no tengo mucho conocimiento en el tema, y no se como declarar en el Main la variable para enviar el texto a la funcion, dejare el codigo y donde me tira error. Disculpa mi ignorancia en el tema ya que no tengo mucho conocimiento. Dejo abajo el codigo señalando donde me tira error